# Android turn off scrolling animation

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, flags, smoothing

How do I stop an Android `scrollview` from having the inertia scrolling? Default use is when I scroll faster it keeps scrolling further after I lift my finger from the device.

I would like it to just stop scrolling when I let go. Is there a flag in the XML for a `scrollview` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [setSmoothScrollbarEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setSmoothScrollingEnabled%28boolean%29)-method which should deactivate this behavior. It also has a XML-Attribute called [smoothScrollbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3asmoothScrollbar).

Comment: Hey, thats what I am attempting to implement right now. I would like an XML way to do it since that would just be a simple `android:method` in the XML file.

Comment: You should check the Android Doc sometimes: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:smoothScrollbar)

Comment: Thanks, I am just going to go with a webview for this implementation